# Type Error after adding localstorage to store

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

On the initial page load I get a Type Error:

500
$rating.join is not a function
TypeError: $rating.join is not a function

This stops after a page change, for example, going to the about page and then back to the index page it will load properly.

I'm thinking it's an order of operations problem? Fixed by onMount? Just not sure how to implement it.

```
// Store
export const rating = writable(browser && (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("rating")) || []))
rating.subscribe((val) => browser && sessionStorage.setItem("rating", JSON.stringify(val)))

// Filters Component
<script>
  import {rating} from "../stores/items";
  const ratings = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
</script>

  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <!-- Ratings Filter -->
    <div class="multiselect">
      <div class="selectBox rounded-sm shadow2 m-1 px-1" on:click={multiselect}>
        <select>
          <option
            >{#if $rating.length === 0}
              Rating:
            {:else}
              {$rating.join(", ")}
            {/if}</option
          >
        </select>
      <div class="overSelect dropdown" />
    </div>
    <div class="checkboxes" id="ratingDropdown">
      {#each ratings as ratings}
      <div class="flex">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={ratings}
          name="typeValues"
          bind:group={$rating}
          value={ratings}
          class="dropdown"
        />
        <label for={ratings} class="dropdown">{ratings}</label>
      </div>
      {/each}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: a `500` error is a server error. The error is in your server code. It appears that the PHP variable `$rating` does't exist or is not a the correct data type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your brackets are wrong in the initial call

```js
const rating = writable(
   browser && 
   (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("rating")) || [])
)
```

This would mean that during SSR rating will be `false`

You probably want to shift them around:

```js
const rating = writable(
   (browser && JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("rating"))) || 
   []
)
```

This way when browser is false, you will get an emptry array.

(The awkward formatting is to try making it visible what happens)

Comment: This fixed it, thanks!

Comment: To clarify for any future people that have the same problem, it ended up looking like this: export const rating = writable((browser && JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("rating")) || []))

Answer (score 0):

console.log ($rating) and see what you get.